# Update nested struct in spark dataset from another struct column

Tags: json, dataframe, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, dataset

I have the following spark dataset with a nested struct type:

```text
-- _1: struct (nullable = false)
 |    |-- _1: struct (nullable = false)
 |    |    |-- _1: struct (nullable = false)
 |    |    |    |-- ni_number: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- national_registration_number: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- id_issuing_country: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- doc_type_name: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- brand: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- company_name: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- _2: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- municipality: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- country: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- _2: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- brand_name: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- puk: string (nullable = true)
 |-- _2: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- customer_servicesegment: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- customer_category: string (nullable = true)
```

my aim here is to do some flattening at the bottom of the structype and have this target schema:

```text
-- _1: struct (nullable = false)
|    |-- _1: struct (nullable = false)
|    |    |-- _1: struct (nullable = false)
|    |    |    |-- ni_number: string (nullable = true)
|    |    |    |-- national_registration_number: string (nullable = true)
|    |    |    |-- id_issuing_country: string (nullable = true)
|    |    |    |-- doc_type_name: string (nullable = true)
|    |    |    |-- brand: string (nullable = true)
|    |    |    |-- company_name: string (nullable = true)
|    |    |-- _2: struct (nullable = true)
|    |    |    |-- municipality: string (nullable = true)
|    |    |    |-- country: string (nullable = true)
|    |-- _2: struct (nullable = true)
|    |    |-- brand_name: string (nullable = true)
|    |    |-- puk: string (nullable = true)
|    |-- _3: struct (nullable = true)
|    |    |-- customer_servicesegment: string (nullable = true)
|    |    |-- customer_category: string (nullable = true)
```

the part of the schema with the columns (`customer_servicesegment`, `customer_category`) should be at the same level as the one with the cols (`brand_name`, `puk`)

So here explode utility from spark sql can be used but I don't know where to put it

any help with this please

Answer (score 1):

If you have Spark 3.1+, you can use [`withField`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.Column.withField.html) column method to update the the struct `_1` like this:

```scala
val df2 = df.withColumn("_1", col("_1").withField("_3", col("_2"))).drop("_2")
```

This adds the column `_2` as new field named `_3` into the struct `_1` then drops the column `_2` for first level.

---

For older versions, you need to reconstruct the struct column `_1`:

```scala
val df2 = df.withColumn(
  "_1", 
  struct(col("_1._1").as("_1"), col("_1._2").as("_2"), col("_2").as("_3"))
).drop("_2")
```

Comment: I have spark 2.4 @blackbishop

Comment: @scalacode then you'll need to recreate the struct `_1` when updating it. Please see my edit.